# Sylius - How to inject FactoryInterface to my own Factory

Tags: sylius

i'm trying to make my own Factory for Sylius form.

Searching in to Sylius components i found how to do.

Here is my Factory:

```
class CommentFactory implements CommentFactoryInterface
{
/**
 * @var FactoryInterface
 */
 private $factory;

/**
 * @param FactoryInterface $factory
 */
public function __construct(FactoryInterface $factory)
{
    $this->factory = $factory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function createNew()
{
    return $this->factory->createNew();
}

public function createWithPost($postId)
{
    $comment = $this->createNew();
    $comment->setPost($postId);

    return $comment;
}
}
```

I can't find how to inject the FactoryInterface of Sylius.

I executed `php app/console debug:container | grep factory` to search the service but doesn't appears :(

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood you have problem with service declaration. Am I right?

For the class you provided above you have to register its as a service, which will decorates a default one. It is a regular service declaration with additional `decorates` attribute in xml.

```
    <service id="app.custom_factory.comment" class="App\Factory\CommentFactory" decorates="app.factory.comment">
        <argument type="service" id="app.custom_factory.comment.inner" />
    </service>
```

Some additional reading about service decoration you can find [in symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/service_container/service_decoration.html). In Sylius documentation however, you can find an information [how to inject your custom factory to controller](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusResourceBundle/create_resource.html#using-custom-factory-method).

Comment: Looks good, ill try tomorrow and say how it works :) Thanks lchrusciel

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot @lchrusciel